# Laravel pass a variable success message back to controller from repoistory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, error-handling

Hi Im using a repository pattern in laravel and to create tasks and they all have an estimated time and the project has a capacity of hours. So i need to pass this back when the task is created so they can see how many hours are left.

I have this so far:

TaskRepository.php

```
public function createTask(array $attributes)
    {

        if ($this->validator->createATask($attributes)) {

            $newAttributes = [
                'project_id' => $attributes['project_id'],
                'estimated_time' => $attributes['estimated_time'],
                'task_name' => $attributes['task_name']
            ];

            $task = Task::updateOrCreate([
                'task_name' => $attributes['task_name']
            ],
                $newAttributes);

            $task->save();

            $project = Project::find($attributes["project_id"])->pluck('capacity_hours');
            $tasks = Task::find($attributes["project_id"])->lists('estimated_time');
            $tasksTotal = array_sum($tasks);
            $capcity_left = ($project - $tasksTotal);
            return $capcity_left;
        }
        throw new ValidationException('Could not create Task', $this->validator->getErrors());

    }
```

and in my controller I have this:

TaskController.php

```
public function store() {

    try {
        $this->task_repo->createTask(Input::all());
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {

        if (Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json(['errors' => $e->getErrors()], 422);
        } else {
            return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($e->getErrors());
        }

    }

    if (Request::ajax()) {
        return Response::json(["message" => "Task added",'capcity_left'=> $capcity_left]);
    } else {
        return Redirect::back()->with('success', true)->with(['message', 'Task added', 'capcity_left'=>$capcity_left ]);
    }

}
```

and I have a partial for errrors:

```
@if(Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span
                    aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <strong>{{ Session::get('message', '') }} Capacity Left:{{ Session::get('capcity_left', '') }}</strong>
    </div>
@endif
```

However I get this error:

`Undefined variable: capcity_left`

Any ideas how I can pass this back to the controller? I thought I was by saying  `return $capcity_left;` Do I need to catch this in the controller? If so how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign the return value of the `createTask` method when calling it from the controller. So you need to do this:

```
public function store() {

    try {
        // assign the return value here
        $capcity_left = $this->task_repo->createTask(Input::all());
    } catch (ValidationException $e) {

    // ...
}
```

Comment: great that works! but the `'message', 'Task added'`  isn't rendered using `{{ Session::get('message', '') }} {{ Session::get('capcity_left', '') }}`